# Запретить доступ к папке для пользователя, а не для php

Tags: .htaccess

С помощью htaccess нужно заблокировать папку _media и все лежащие в ней папки и файлы. Как говорится, обрубить на корню. Но важно, чтобы папка было заблокирована для доступа через браузерную строку, а также для поисковых роботов, но не для php. Мне нужно подключаться к файлам в этой папке. Ну и не только с помощью PHP. Например, `<img src="_media/img/logo.jpg">` также должно работать.

Comment: `<img src="_media/img/logo.jpg">` это и есть «доступ через браузерную строку». Кажется стоит подучить матчасть, в особенности как вообще работает http и браузеры.

Answer (score 1):

А вы картинку порежьте на n частей, по img на каждую; скачать можно, но склеивать...

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, вам надо запретить выводить список файлов.
Создайте в папке файл .htaccess с содержимым

```
Options -Indexes
```

и рестартуйте апач

Comment: Мне нужно запретить доступ к файлу. Если человек в адресной строке введет https://мойсайт.ру/_media/img/1.jpg - ему должно вывести ошибку, а не картинку. И так для всех файлов в папке _media. 2 часа возился, не получается

Comment: и не получится. Если файл может быть указан напрямую в img src то он может быть открыт напрямую

Comment: более того, если вы закроете доступ к папке вообще, сделаете скрипт, который отдаёт картинки по ссылке типа img.php?imgid=111 то браузерможет показать картинку напрямую по этой же ссылке. Максимум что у вас получится сделать - это "запрет" на копирование картинки/ссылке по правому клику (например натянуть сверху прозрачный div) но и это не поможет напрямую забрать картинку тому кто умеет devtools браузерный.

Comment: @Sheridan, хмм, а как же авторизация?

Comment: А куда она денется?

Comment: @Sheridan, "денется" - картинка или авторизация? я хочу сказать а как же блокировка контента для незарегистрированных пользователей - из ваших слов следует что это не возможно

Comment: Да заблокировать для незарегестрированных можно. Можно даже показывать с яркими ватермарками и так далее. Автор то не того хочет. Автор хочет "запретить доступ к файлам не запрещая доступа к файлам". Веб так не работает, как он хочет. Пожалуй единственный вариант, который можно считать приемлемым - затруднить скачивание такой картинки. Ктото в стили ссылку прячет, ктото дивом сверху кроет, ктото режет на части. А то и всё вместе.

Comment: На сайте есть файлы, которые не должны быть проиндексированы ПСками или открыты по ссылке, так как это личная информация конкретного юзера. Как это еще можно сделать?

Comment: Если файл не может быть открыт по ссылке - у браузера не будет к нему доступа. И опять же, какая цель всего этого? от чего хотите защититься? Чтобы файл не перехватили по пути? Ну так ssl это обеспечит. Чтобы данные юзера не украли? Ну так шифруйте их солёным паролем юзера. А с юзерской стороны сам юзер пусть обеспечивает безопасность своих данных: сложный пароль, логаут при отсутствии необходимости и так далее.